# Getting non-const iterator using declval

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14, decltype

A minimal example that shows two ways of getting an iterator type that I would naively expect to give the same type as a result:

```
template <typename Range>
struct foo
{
    using iterator = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<Range>()));
    using iterator2 = typename Range::iterator;

    static_assert(std::is_same<iterator, iterator2>::value, "Iterator types differ!");
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    foo<decltype(v)> f;
}
```

But this actually triggers the static assert.

If we change the first iterator to:

```
using iterator = decltype(std::declval<Range>().begin());
```

no static assert is fired.

Looking at the definition of `std::begin()`, this is overloaded for both reference and const-reference types. Since `declval` gives back an rvalue-reference, this will only bind to a const reference, thus giving back a const iterator type.

This can be worked around with something of an abomination, using reference collapsing:

```
using iterator = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<typename std::add_lvalue_reference<Range>::type>()));
```

Is there an easier way of getting a non-const iterator? Obviously `typename Range::iterator` isn't going to exist for all types (e.g. `T*`), and likewise for the member `begin()`, thus neither are ideal.

Comment: The "abomination" can be shortened to `decltype(std::begin(std::declval<Range&>()))`.

Comment: `std::begin` does not exists for `T*`, it only exists for arrays (i.e., `T (&)[N]`).

Answer (score 3):

Calling `std::begin` directly is not even the correct way of getting a begin iterator. The correct idiom requires two statements: `using std::begin; begin(rng);`. Which obviously you can't do in a `decltype`.

The way you're doing it won't work for types that don't have a member `begin`/`end` or a `std::begin/end` overload.

So the correct solution is to create a function that does this:

```
template<typename Range>
auto my_begin(Range &&rng)
{
  using std::begin;
  return begin(std::forward<Range>(rng));
}
```

And then invoke that function in your `decltype` field.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is `using` statement necessary in here? `using std::begin; begin(rng);`

Comment: @bartop: I explained why: it otherwise won't work for types without a member begin/end. This syntax uses ADL, but you need to have `std::begin` there in case ADL fails so that it will call the member begin. And it has specializations for array types and such.